# anyone know how to solve this real option problem (derivative securities)?

Tags: options, derivatives, securities

[image: screenshot of the entire problem]

The purpose of the question is to determine the 'replicating portfolio' of options that is equivalent to the project described. The equation for the profits from the project should be: $25M - 10,000*(Price of diamond)-$12M or $13M - 10,000 *(Price). Solving for the price I got $1300 to be the break-even price. From what my teacher said, that means the project cash flows are equivalent to selling 10,000 put options with a strike price of $1300. From the given put option prices this implies the project should be 10,000* (Price of put options with strike= 1300) or 10,000 * 337.2. I tried inputting the answer but it doesn't work. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: We don't do homework or exams here, if it relates to your real life personal finance sure tell us but otherwise please study the material, consult the instructor and take your exam.

Comment: Why are you using the European option price?